# Rear wheel squeak Motorcycle (video link)

Tags: motorcycle, wheels, squeaking

My rear wheel is squeaking. It has a new brake disc, new pads and new bearings in wheel and sprocket hub with new dust seals.

Is the noise anything to worry about? The wheel moves freely nicely by hand with no brake drag sound. The brake disc does get warm to the touch after a 13-mile ride at 80 mph but I am coming to a stop in maybe 600 yards so would that explain the heat?

A video can be found at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YPs5YSJDNsQ
Cheers

Comment: Sounds bad to me.  First thought is wheel bearings.

Comment: I should add it's not constant.Only at really slow rotation and not the whole rotation. If it the bearings what could be the issue? Cheers

Comment: It not the bearings then it's the brake dragging.  Check the rotor for runout against the max. runout spec in the bike's service manual.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a few things...
It's not unusual to get a slight rubbing noise from new brakes, but this sounds like something that warrants at least further investigation, as it's a bit more than just a new pad to disk contact noise.

Firstly though.. just check that the chain is not far too tight. This can cause similar noises sometimes especially if the chain has tight spots. The load from the chain can really pull on the rear sprocket if tight & load up the rubber sprocket/hub cushion which can bind. If the chain is too tight, adjust it to the correct specs.

The new pads could also be binding causing this noise, especially if the caliper/pads are not floating/sliding freely, or the pistons are sticking. Although this should have been checked and lubricated properly when the brakes were done.

Try 'very carefully' to push the pads/pistons back into the brake caliper a little bit with a small prybar or screwdriver, just to create a small gap between pads and disk.. Is the noise still there? 
If the noise has gone then the brakes need looking at again as they are binding which is giving you this noise. They may not be operating correctly, or as smoothly as they should be.

If the noise is still there after you've checked the chain and made sure that the pads aren't binding on the disk, then it could be a bearing that's causing the noise. Brand new bearings don't normally give issues, but they can be installed incorrectly, sometimes ending up misaligned or overcompressed etc which means that they don't rotate smoothly.

Comment: Cheers I'll pull the pads back and check although the wheel does spin freely with not much pad sound. The chain is fine also I've just adjusted and noise was there when it was a little loose. The bearings went in straight all the way using the old bearings as drivers. I put a very very light layer of grease inside the wheel hub to stop any corrosion getting between the hub and the bearing.

Answer (score 0):

Castle nut is too tight. Loosen it up and see if the squeal goes away.

Comment: was at 84nm but lowered it to 75nm.I'll see if that makes a difference although the manual says it should be 88nm

Comment: I can't think of anything else it could be. Neither the bearings, chain, or brake pads cause squeaks. Unless the pads are completely gone, but you said you just put some on. So either the castle nut is too tight or the wheel isn't perfectly straight.

Comment: Ah so we can rule out bearings completley? The wheel alignment is all good.Maybe my torque wrench is off who knows, hopefully loosening it slightly will stop the squeek, I'll find out tomorrow.

Comment: Still hapening after loosening the nut. It happens when pushing down on the rear which makes me think shock absorber again,this is confusing me somewhat.

Comment: If it's not the castle nut being too tight then I'm stumped as well. Got nothing to do with your shock seeing as it squeaks when barely moving it. Loosen your chain adjusters as well. Loosen everything.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this occurs due to "dried out" bearings and not due the disk brake OR the chain. A good way to confirm this is to raise the rear wheel, mark a point around its circumference and slowly rotate it. If the issue is the disc brake the noise will be heard at specific position of the wheel. You can do the same with the chain, just clean a link and rotate the wheel checking if the noise occurs at specific chain position. If none of these stand, slowly rotate the wheel and expect for a small "step" (or more) in it's movement. Finally remove the wheel axle, lube it carefully with some grease, check the bearings by rotating them with your finger (and confirm no "steps" on their rotation) apply grease as well on them and reassemble. Otherwise change bearings and along with them their seals.

Comment: Thanks, its still doing the noise after this time and the mechanic didn;t mention anything about it at the MOT. Unfortunatley the bearings in it are new. The wheel will be coming off soon for new chain and sprockets and ill check how much lube is in them then. Thanks